# Using geometry without modifying default margins

Tags: margins, geometry

I would like to use the package `geometry` since it's a convenient tool to change margin *locally* in my `book` document. The problem is that the simple fact to call it in the preamble modifies the default margins everywhere.

Is it possible to load the package without modifying LaTeX default margins?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` will not change any parameter, but will allow using `\newgeometry`.